# Function error from category drop-down button

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have this category:

[image]

When I press the drop-down button, it should only drop one type but here it drops 3 types at the same time. Where did I go wrong?
Here is the blade:

```
@foreach($loai as $l => $type)
    <ul style="list-style:none">

      <li>
        <span style="font-size: 17px"><a href="{{URL::to('/loai-san-pham/'.$type->type_id)}}">{{$type->type_name}}</a></span>
        
        <span class="items-sidebar">v</span>

      </li>

      @foreach($hang as $h)
          @if($h->brand_type==1)
              <ul class="brand_category">
                  <li>
                      <a href="{{route('hangsanpham',$h->brand_id)}}">{{$h->brand_name}}</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          @endif
      @endforeach

      <ul class="type_category" style="display: none"></ul>

    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Here is the drop-down function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.items-sidebar').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('ul').find('.brand_category',).toggle();
    });
    $('.items-sidebar').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('ul').find('.type_category',).toggle();
    });
```

Do I have problem in the blade or the js function?? Please help..

Comment: Would you please post the HTML of the dropdown as it appears in your browser? This would make it easier to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting all brand_category of your all parents elements.
and also there is a non necessary comma inside your find method.

try this on

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.items-sidebar').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('ul').find('.brand_category').toggle();
    });
    $('.items-sidebar').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('ul').find('.type_category').toggle();
    });
</script>
```